# Two ListViews in a vertical LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-listview, android-linearlayout

I need to arrange two `ListView`s in a vertical `LinearLayout` in such a way that 2nd ListView will be at the end of last item of first ListView.

If ListView1 is empty, the view should be something like this.

[image: First ListView is empty]

As ListView1.size() increases ListView2 should be pulled down to a limit.

[image]

ListView1 reaches a fixed height (or weight) , it should stop expanding and start scrolling. 
[image]

I think there is no method in android to set maxHeight for `View`.

I have already tried almost all combinations of layout_height="wrap_content", fixed heights and weights for both ListViews.  In all cases,
either 1st requirement(image1) will fail : ListView1 will not be at top
or last requirement(image3) will fail : ListView2 will get pushed out of the screen.

Any help or suggestions will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

**Edit:**

my current code is:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/myOrderListView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="0.6" >
    </ListView>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/myCompletedOrderListView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.4" >
    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

I have tried with different weight combinations, like:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/myOrderListView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.6" >
    </ListView>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/myCompletedOrderListView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.4" >
    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

But it will fail last requirement.

**Edit2:** @dangVarmit

```
    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/myOrderListView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ListView>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/myCompletedOrderListView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp" >
    </ListView>

    <Space
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

If you mean this, It still fails req3.

Comment: What did you tried so far?

Comment: negative voting means you dont know? or you will not help? or i should not ask? or its a wrong question? or there is no solution? or ? I spend more than two days on this and i couldnt find ant solution.

Comment: try changing android:layout_height in your first xml to android:layout_height="0dp", as you did for your first ListView

Comment: @JuanAguilarGuisado Already tried that (layout_height="0dp" of ListView2). But no Luck :-(

Comment: @Vijeesh trying this which requirement fails? the first? I mean... if it's the first, you can try setting your ListView1 visibility to ListView.GONE when its size is 0. Doing this, it won't take you clear space ;) Good luck!

Comment: @JuanAguilarGuisado No. It will still break 3rd req. And if i use View.GONE when size is 0, then it will fail req1 on size = 1,2,3, etc till height of ListView1 reaches ListView2, then onwards req3 will break.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the below code for right and left listview you can change it to above and bottom listview or as you want to show
main_activity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_top_bit"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="@color/orange">

            <LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="horizontal">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button_1"
                    style="@style/landscape_top_button"
                    android:text="button1" />
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button_2"
                    style="@style/landscape_top_button"
                    android:text="button2"/>
            </LinearLayout>


        </LinearLayout>
        <View android:id="@+id/main_horizontal_bar"
            android:layout_height="3dip" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:background="@color/gray" android:layout_marginTop="1dip" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/lower_linear_layout"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/main_top_bit">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_below="@+id/lower_linear_layout"
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="150dip"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:background="@color/teal"
                android:id="@+id/org_left_linearlayout2">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button_3"
                    style="@style/landscape_top_button"
                    android:text="button3"/>
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button_4"
                    style="@style/landscape_top_button"
                    android:text="button4" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <ListView
                android:background="@color/green"
                android:id="@+id/lstLeft"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/org_left_linearlayout2"
                android:layout_above="@+id/org_left_bottom_rl"
                android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"/>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/org_left_bottom_rl"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:background="@color/purple" >

                <Button
                    android:text="button5"
                    android:id="@+id/button_5"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                </Button>
            </RelativeLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <View
            android:layout_width="3dip"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="@color/gray">
        </View>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_below="@+id/lower_linear_layout"
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"

            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:background="@color/olive"
                android:id="@+id/org_right_linearlayout2">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button_6"
                    style="@style/landscape_top_button"
                    android:text="button6" />
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button_7"
                    style="@style/landscape_top_button"
                    android:text="button7" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/lstRight"
                android:background="@color/blue"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/org_right_linearlayout2"
                android:layout_above="@+id/org_right_bottom_rl"
                android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"/>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/org_right_bottom_rl"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/red"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

                <Button
                    android:text="button8"
                    android:id="@+id/button_8"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                </Button>
            </RelativeLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private final String TAG =  this.getClass().getName();
    ListView leftList;
    ListView rightList;


     static final String[] FRUITS = new String[] {"Apple", "Bananna", "Cherry", "Pear", "Strawberry"};
     static final String[] VEGETABLES = new String[] {"Asparagus", "Bamboo shoots", "Celery", "Ginger", "Spinach"};

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        leftList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lstLeft);
        rightList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lstRight);      

        populateLeftList();
        populateRightList();
    }

    public void populateLeftList(){
        leftList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<string>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, FRUITS));  
    }

    public void populateRightList(){
        rightList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<string>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, VEGETABLES));
    }
}
```

Comment: It is simple to implement Left and right ListViews since height of one  ListView is not depends on the Height of the next one. But in my case it is... ;-(

Comment: actually, position of 2nd ListView depends upon Height of 1st ListView.

Answer (score 0):

- for list1, layout_height=wrap_content, remove layout_weight
- for list2, layout_height=100dp (any fixed value), remove layout_weight
- add <Space layout_weight=1 layout_height=0dp/> at the end of the list.

that should give you the results you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I have found one solution by myself. It works perfectly as i wanted. I dont know whether it is a good approach or not. I am searching for an xml solution.

`getDeviceHeight()` is my method to find device height in pixels.
200 is the approximate height of other ui elements above My ListViews.
`myorderList` is my first ListView

```
if(myorderList.getHeight() > ((getDeviceHeight()/2) - 200)) {
    LayoutParams params = myorderList.getLayoutParams();
    params.height = (int)((getDeviceHeight()/2) - 200);
    myorderList.setLayoutParams(params);
}
```

This should be done when there is any kind of changes happening to the first ListView.

**Edit:**
This will also fail when items removed after reaching maximum height :-(